# extract specific text from image by using easyocr

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, text, text-extraction

I use easy OCR to extract text from images, and it works well for me. However, I need to remove shaded numbers from the extracted text result. I need to erase text if it's shaded.
Any help?? For example in the following picture, I need to delete "2586" and extract only "2574"
[image]

Comment: Do you mean strikethrough ?

Comment: What does EasyOCR do with these ?

Comment: it removes the line and expects the numbers behind this,
For example: the first line will be (25862574) and I need to remove 2586 and the result should be 2574.

Comment: So you mean that the strikethrough digits are read faithfully ? Does EasyOCR return some "quality" score ?

Comment: yes i mean that the strikethrough digits are read faithfully and it return quality score of each cell

Comment: Yes, I mean that the strikethrough digits are read faithfully and it returns a quality score of each cell ,but it considers 25862574 as one cell

Comment: If the lines a perfect horizontals like in your sample, then detection is easy, by counting horizontally.